# Is there a method to condense multiple if statements with different functions into something shorter in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently creating a calculator that asks the user a series of questions to calculate the answer to their sum, however I have quickly come across the fact that I am using multiple if statements, and it has made my code extremely difficult and tiring to read.

I would like to know if there is an alternative method to using multiple if statements that each have a different function that takes up less space and completes the same task.

Here's a sample of my code:

```js
def decision():
    choice = input("""
Please Select an Option:

Type 1 for Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication and Division.
Type 2 for Squares or Square Roots, Cubes or Cube Roots, Powers, Roots and Percentages.
Type 3 for Greater Than and Less Than.
Type 4 for H.C.F(Highest Common Factor), G.C.D(Greatest Common Divisor) and L.C.M(Least Common Multiple).
Type 5 for Converting Degrees to Radians.

Type 6 for Calculating Grades from Marks.
Type 7 for Perimeter, Circumference, Area, Surface Area and Volume of Shapes.

Selection: """)

    if choice == '1':
        ASMD()

    elif choice == '2':
        SCERP()

    elif choice == '3':
        GL()

    elif choice == '4':
        HCF_GCD_LCM()

    elif choice == '5':
        DR()

    elif choice == '6':
        CG()

    elif choice == '7':
        PCASAV()

    else:
        print("You have not selected a Valid Option. Please run the program again.")

        input("Press Enter to continue...")
        exit()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

Comment: I also remember answering something similar in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/126746/viewing-test-scores-from-one-of-three-csv-files/126748#126748